# MySQL cant use Alias in WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT MIN(deals_bookings.date) as booking_date, `users`.`company_cvrnr`, `users`.`company_debnr`, `refnumbers`.`refno` 
FROM `refnumbers` 
JOIN `deals` ON (`refnumbers`.`deal_id` = `deals`.`ID`)
JOIN `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `deals`.`partner_id`) 
LEFT JOIN deals_bookings ON (deals_bookings.deal_id = deals.ID)
WHERE `refnumbers`.`is_claimed` = '1'
AND booking_date >= '2013-11-21'
AND `refnumbers`.`claimed_at` BETWEEN '2013-11-26 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-26 23:59:59' 
GROUP by refno
ORDER BY `refnumbers`.`claimed_at` DESC
```

This is the query I try to execute. Problem occurs when I have the line

```
AND booking_date >= '2013-11-21'
```

I get the error Unknown column. What am I doing wrong?

With MIN(deals_bookings.date) I am trying to get the row and "date" column inside deals_bookings, with the lowest date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This ...

The problem is that the WHERE clause is executed before the SELECT statement. And thus the booking_date column is not yet available.
The HAVING clause is executed after the SELECT statement. It kinds of filter the resulst out after you have selected everything.

```
SELECT MIN(deals_bookings.date) as booking_date, `users`.`company_cvrnr`, `users`.`company_debnr`, `refnumbers`.`refno` 
FROM `refnumbers` 
JOIN `deals` ON (`refnumbers`.`deal_id` = `deals`.`ID`)
JOIN `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `deals`.`partner_id`) 
LEFT JOIN deals_bookings ON (deals_bookings.deal_id = deals.ID)
WHERE `refnumbers`.`is_claimed` = '1'
AND `refnumbers`.`claimed_at` BETWEEN '2013-11-26 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-26 23:59:59' 
GROUP by refno
HAVING MIN(deals_bookings.date) >= '2013-11-21'
ORDER BY `refnumbers`.`claimed_at` DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `having` clause

```
SELECT MIN(deals_bookings.date) as booking_date, `users`.`company_cvrnr`, `users`.`company_debnr`, `refnumbers`.`refno` 
FROM `refnumbers` 
JOIN `deals` ON (`refnumbers`.`deal_id` = `deals`.`ID`)
JOIN `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `deals`.`partner_id`) 
LEFT JOIN deals_bookings ON (deals_bookings.deal_id = deals.ID)
WHERE `refnumbers`.`is_claimed` = '1'
AND `refnumbers`.`claimed_at` BETWEEN '2013-11-26 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-26 23:59:59' 
GROUP by refno
HAVING booking_date >= '2013-11-21'
ORDER BY `refnumbers`.`claimed_at` DESC
```

since `booking_date` is aggregated data.